# Smooth Map between real proyective spaces

Tags: calculus, geometry, manifolds

Let $P: R^{n+1}\setminus 0 → R^{k+1}\setminus 0$ be a smooth function and suppose that from some d integer, $P (\lambda x )= (\lambda)^{d} P(x)$ with $\lambda$ a real number different from $0$.

Show that $P^{´}: PR^{n} → PR^{k}$ defined by $P^{´}([x])=[P(x)]$ is well defined and smooth

Any ideas on how to proof this?
Thanks

Comment: what was meant by the failed notation ?

Comment: $R^{n}$  and $R^{k}$ both without the origin

Comment: The idea is that the map $R^{n+1} \to PR^n$ is a submersion, or, if you want, around every point of $PR^n$ there is a section of the map $s \colon U \to R^{n+1}$ so that $\pi \circ s = id_U$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I include the fact that P is an homogeneus function of degree d?